# Preventing RabbitMQ from blocking upstream services

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, rabbitmq

I have a Spring application that consumes messages on a specific port (say 9001), restructures them and then forwards to a Rabbit MQ server.  The code segment is:

```
private void send(String routingKey, String message) throws Exception { 
        String exchange = applicationConfiguration.getAMQPExchange();  
        String exchangeType = applicationConfiguration.getAMQPExchangeType();

        Connection connection = myConnection.getConnection();
        Channel channel = connection.createChannel();
        channel.exchangeDeclare(exchange, exchangeType);
        channel.basicPublish(exchange, routingKey, null, message.getBytes());

        log.debug(" [CORE: AMQP] Sent message with key {} : {}",routingKey, message);
    }
```

If the Rabbit MQ server fails (crashes, runs out of RAM, turned off etc) the code above blocks, preventing the upstream service from receiving messages (a bad thing).  I am looking for a way of preventing this behaviour whilst not losing mesages so that at some time in the future they can be resent.

I am not sure how best to address this.  One option may be to queue the messages to a disk file and then use a separate thread to read and forward to the Rabbit MQ server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the issue you are describing is a known JDK socket behaviour when the connection is lost mid-write. See this mailing list thread: http://markmail.org/thread/3vw6qshxsmu7fv6n.

Note that if RabbitMQ is shut down, the TCP connection should be closed in a way that's quickly observable by the client. However, it is true that stale TCP connections can take
a while to be detected, that's why RabbitMQ's core protocol has heartbeats. Set heartbeat
interval to a low value (say, 6-8) and the client itself will notice unresponsive peer
in that amount of time.

You need to use Publisher confirms [1] but also account for the fact that the app itself
can go down right before sending a message. As you rightly point out, having a disk-based
WAL (write-ahead log) is a common solution for this problem. Note that it is both quite
tricky to get right and still leaves *some* time window where your app process shutting down can result in an unpublished and unlogged message.

No promises on the time frame but the idea of adding WAL to the Java client has been discussed.

1. http://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html

Comment: Michael, thank you for your answer.  I guess there are multiple issues here including the source application locking as it is trying to send a message to a server that is not responding (as it has failed).  Some sort of threaded asynchronous system based on a FIFO may address this - would that make sense?  I should add that the reference was useful - even to know that there are others who have identified this issue!

Comment: An outgoing message buffer (which is a FIFO queue, just in the client itself) would help preserve the messages for redelivery. It will not help make unresponsive peer detection, though, but a low heartbeat timeout will.